# How can I obtain the elements in a single list with specified indices?

Tags: python, list, indices

Suppose I have a list

```
li = ['a0','b0','c0','a1','b1','c1',...,'an','bn','cn']
```

I want to obtain

```
['a0',...,'an'], ['b0',...,'bn'], ['c0',...,'cn']
```

using a for loop. I'm trying to do something like

```
for i in range(3): # for a,b,c
    lis = [li[i][k] for i in range(n+1)] # Hope to get [a0,...,an], etc
    print(lis)
```

However, this method won't work because there's no sublist here. I don't think I can do something like `i*k` because the indices start at 0. How can I obtain the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create different slices:

```
count = 3 
main_list = ['a0', 'b0', 'c0', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'an', 'bn', 'cn']

for i in range(count):
    sub_list = main_list[i::count]
    
    print(sub_list)
```

Or use a list comprehension if you want to create a list of sublists:

```
count = 3
main_list = ['a0', 'b0', 'c0', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'an', 'bn', 'cn']
sub_lists = [main_list[i::count] for i in range(count)]

print(sub_lists)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider `li[::3]`, `li[1::3]`, `li[2::3]`.

You can use the powerful Python slicing facility.

`print(li[::3])` would print `['a0','a1',...,'an']`

`print(li[1::3])` would print `['b0','b1',...,'bn']`

`print(li[2::3])` would print `['c0','c1',...,'cn']`

In Python slice notation `[x:y:z]` means take a slice from `x` to `y` skipping `z-1` elements in between, i.e. take elements with indices `x`, `x+z`, up to but not including `y`